# Typo3 Powermail: false spam alert with required fields

Tags: typo3, powermail

I have a powermail form. I get the following error when I submit the form:

```
Spam recognized: uid11 This field must be filled!
Spam recognized: uid12 This field must be filled!
Spam recognized: uid14 This field must be filled!
Spam recognized: uid13 This field must be filled!
```

The fields uid11 ... uid14 do exist in the form - and they are transmitted to the server. For example (from Chrome network tab):

```
Testvalue
------WebKitFormBoundaryIIcUvgTthzftQYb6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="tx_powermail_pi1[field][uid12]"
```

The 4 fields which are claimed are mandatory (required) but have no other rules added.

I have already tried to disable the spam check, but without any success:

```
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.spamshield._enable = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that in table `tx_powermail_domain_model_field` the field for "marker"was empty. I have no idea why I have to add a marker variable, but since I added variable names (like "e_mail", "firstname", etc.) the form works.

Answer (score 1):

Hat the same problem a couple of weeks ago, Disabled the spamshield helped. Later I just disabled badword filter. seems to work for me (check if spamshield is rly disabled in TypoScript Object Browser)

Comment: Spamshield is disabled as far as I can see in the TS Object Browser